# Smart TV Stick (Android) connects to 3g dongle for Internet

Tags: hardware, car-dock

I am trying to explore the options of connecting a 3g dongle to the car charger. And then connecting a Smart TV Android stick into the 3g dongle to get Internet. It will be great if I can get internet from the USB connection and not have to waste Wifi (how ever little) battery between the 2 devices.

Questions

- Is it possible to get internet via USB on the android stick ?
- Can it get power from the USB too ?
- Will starting the car have bad effects on these devices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get what you want, if you find a model that includes this functionality already (like e.g. the older Archos G9 tablets did) but it will not work out of the box for most models.

There's the autopatcher project ([thread on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1719408)) that enables 3G dongles for modem-less tablets (but it is limited to certain custom ROMs like CyanogenMod, AOSP, rooted Google stock Android and others).

Regarding the power question: That's up to the exact model and you will need to find out by trial and error or get that info from searching Google/specs/etc. The same applies to your last question (but in general, those TV sticks are built to be plugged in and out and need to survive sudden power losses just as phones need to because they tend to run out of battery juice).